# Is it possible to access card details associated with an order using PayPal API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

How to retrieve card details with orderId using PayPal API?

I need to retrieve card details for a specific order using the PayPal API. I have already referred to the official PayPal API documentation (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get), but unfortunately, I couldn't find any information about accessing card details.

I understand that PayPal places a strong emphasis on user privacy and security, and it does not expose sensitive card information, such as the card number or CVV, to third-party integrations or APIs. However, I still need to gather certain card details associated with an order for further processing within my application.

If anyone has experience or knowledge about how to retrieve card details using the PayPal API, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this. If there are any alternative methods or workarounds to retrieve the necessary card details, please share them as well.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For [standard PayPal payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which includes the expanding black 'Debit or Credit Card' inline guest form, no card details nor any information about the funding source used is returned. It could be card, or the PayPal balance, or a bank account, or one of various other local payment methods. All the receiving account knows, and all that is returned via the API, is whether a PayPal payment was completed and received successfully.

For [advanced](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/) integrations, the last few digits of the card and some other details are returned in the capture response.